# «Руб./мес.» или «руб/мес»?

Tags: орфография, сокращения, косая-черта

Как правильно?

> Мой доход руб./мес. — 2500 рубчонков.

> Мой доход руб/мес — 2500 рубчонков.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

• Вот что имеется в ПАС ([§ 210](https://orfogrammka.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80_%D0%B8_%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85_%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9/)):

> Косолинейные сокращения употребляются **вместо словосочетаний**, реже — сложных слов, напр.: *а/я* (абонементный ящик), *к/т* (кинотеатр), *х/б* (хлопчатобумажный), *об/мин* (оборот в минуту), *р/с* и *р/сч* (расчетный счет); в этих случаях после сокращенных элементов слов **точки не ставятся** [выделено мной. — Р. М.].

Рубли в месяц, или рублики в месяц, или рубчонки в месяц — разницы нет.
Все равно пишем ***руб/мес*** (без точек).

•• Ни один из предложенных вами вариантов не является верным.
Если в начале предложения уже указана единица измерения, то рядом с числом она не ставится — как в таблицах (кол-во, шт. — 10; масса, кг — 75; скорость, км/ч — 100).

••• Возможные варианты:

Мой доход, руб/мес — 2500.
Мой доход в месяц — 2500 рубчонков.
Мой доход — 2500 руб/мес.
Ежемесячный доход — 2500 руб.

Answer (score 2):

***Мой доход руб/мес — 2500 рубчонков.***

[«Грамота.ру»](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=241958):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]